# C# XDocument Element/Elements returns null

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I am trying to read through XML file using XDocument. I have tried many attempts to load it but everything seems to return null.
First attempt:

```
    var doc = XDocument.Load(path);

    var graphml = doc.Root.Element("graphml"); //null
    foreach (var keyElement in graphml.Elements("key")) //exception
      ...
    XElement graph = doc.Element("graph"); //null
    foreach (var nodeElement in graph.Elements("node")) //exception
     ...
```

Another one:

```
    var doc = XDocument.Load(path);
    XName xNameKey = XName.Get("key", doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace().NamespaceName);

    foreach (var keyElement in doc.Elements(xNameKey)) //null
    ...
```

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns">
  <key id="pr" for="edge" attr.name="preference" attr.type="int" />
...
  <graph id="G" edgedefault="undirected">
    <node id="st1" />
    <node id="st2" />
    ...
  </graph>
</graphml>
```

Any ideas about what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In your first example `doc.Root` already gives you the graphml element. There is no element under the root with that name. In your second example you forgot to include the Root.  I expect `foreach (var keyElement in doc.Root.Elements(xNameKey))` to work.

Comment: @rene thank you it helped, can you put it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example `doc.Root` already gives you the `<graphml>` element. There is no element under the root with that name so  `doc.Root.Element("graphml")` will return null in that case.

To complete your first example it should look like this: Notice the XNamespace addition.

```
var graphml = doc.Root;
var ns = (XNamespace)"http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns";
foreach (var keyElement in graphml.Elements(ns + "key")) 
{
   keyElement.Dump();
}
```

In your second example you forgot to include the Root that you correctly used in

```
var xNameKey = XName.Get("key", doc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace().NamespaceName);
```

When your start iterating the elements do so over the Root element:

```
foreach (var keyElement in doc.Root.Elements(xNameKey))
```